# Uploading a reactjs code in github, without the node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github

I want to upload a react app in github. But, I dont want to HOST IT. I only want to keep the codes there. But while uploading, I had problem with uploading the **node_modules** folder. I searched other repo, and even there **node_modules folder** wasn't present. Still their code could be used by running a command called **npm install** or **something similar to that.**

What are the steps to upload **My ReactJS Code** without uploading the **node_modules**. But in such a way, by which anyone can install all the node modules by **npm install** or **something similar** to that?

Comment: Just `.gitignore` the `node_modules/` directory, which e.g. Create React App does by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tell git to exclude something in your project, you use a `.gitignore` file. In the `.gitignore` file, you can add patterns to files or folders and git will not track any of those files.

[Here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Node.gitignore) is a template for Node projects given by GitHub. It excludes the `node_modules` folder. Put it in your project root and remember to rename it to just `.gitignore` (note the period in front).